# Is dark energy made by bosons?

Tags: dark-energy, bosons

Theoretically speaking, would dark energy be made by bosons or similar particles or by a completely new type of particles?

Comment: Dark energy would be due to a spin-$0$ bosonic field on some models (though there are other explanations: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_energy#Alternative_ideas )

Comment: dark ! nobody knows

Answer (score 2):

In the simplest currently theoretically viable explanation of dark energy, it is not made up of fundamental particles, but rather a cosmological constant $\Lambda$, which represents a default energy-momentum content of empty vacuum.

There are all sorts of models that can be constructed to explain the dark energy phenomenon, which could have it associated with many different types of particles, though, as peterh says, ordinary baryonic matter is very unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is unknown. It seems quite probable, that the dark matter is not baryonic (i.e. not the "common" matter from protons, neutrons and electrons).